# Intersection of two lists of variables

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

How to define in ISO Prolog a (meta-logical) predicate for the intersection of two lists of variables that runs in *linear* time? The variables may appear in any determined order.  No implementation dependent property like the "age" of variables must influence the outcome.

In analogy to [`library(ordsets)`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dordsets.html#lib_002dordsets), let's call the relation `varset_intersection(As, Bs, As_cap_Bs).`

```
?- varset_intersection([A,B], [C,D], []).
true.

?-varset_intersection([A,B], [B,A], []).
false.

?- varset_intersection([A,B,C], [C,A,D], Inter).
Inter = [A,C].
or
Inter = [C,A].

?- varset_intersection([A,B],[A,B],[A,C]).
B = C
or
A = B, A = C

?- varset_intersection([A,B,C],[A,B],[A,C]).
idem
```

That is, the third argument is an output argument, that unifies with the intersection of the first two arguments.

See this [list of the built-ins](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#status_quo) from the current ISO standard (ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995 including [Cor.2](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2)).

(Note, that I did answer this question in the course of another one several years ago. However, it remains hidden and invisible to Google.)

Comment: The answer to the first query (`varset_intersection([A,B], [B,A], []).`) is false, right?

Comment: What should be the result of the following queries: `varset_intersection([A,B],[A,B],[A,C]).` and `varset_intersection([A,B,C],[A,B],[A,C]).` Should these goals be satisfied by unifying the *real* intersection with the third argument?

Comment: It should be clear now.

Comment: One thing I need to further understand: by putting that *or* between different results you mean that the goal should be satisfied only once with any of those two results?

Comment: I give up... how to do in O(|L1|+|L2|) ? waiting for some clever 'trick'...

Comment: @TudorBerariu: Only once. You can choose which one. But your choice must not depend on implementation dependent properties like variable age.

Comment: Why wouldn't `B=D, Inter=[A,B,C]` be a solution for the third example query? I don't see the reason for that not being a valid solution but `B=C` being one for the fifth query.

Comment: @TudorBerariu: in `varset_intersection([A,B,C], [C,A,D], Inter)` only `A` and `C` are in the intersection. So why should `B = D`?

Comment: Well, it wasn't clear for me what relation this predicate should express. In that case you could say that if `B = D` then the intersection is `[A,B,C]`. When a list of variables (that also appear in the first two lists) is given as the third argument, unification between variables might happen and lead to some strange results [at least for me] that I could not separate from the one I suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `term_variables/2` works in a time linear with the size of its first argument, then this might work:

```
varset_intersection(As, Bs, As_cap_Bs):-
    term_variables([As, Bs], As_and_Bs),
    term_variables(As, SetAs),
    append(SetAs, OnlyBs, As_and_Bs),
    term_variables([OnlyBs, Bs], SetBs),
    append(OnlyBs, As_cap_Bs, SetBs).
```

Each common variable appears only once in the result list no matter how many times it appears in the two given lists.

```
?- varset_intersection2([A,_C,A,A,A], [A,_B,A,A,A], L).
L = [A].
```

Also, it might give strange results as in this case:

```
?- varset_intersection([A,_X,B,C], [B,C,_Y,A], [C, A, B]).
A = B, B = C.
```

(`permutation/2` might help here).

Comment: The strange result is a consequence of this predicate being meta-logical.

Comment: Does the standard enforce any complexity for predicates like `term_variables/2`?

Comment: None, but the very interface permits an effective implementation in current systems like SICStus, YAP, SWI.

Comment: *Effective* means *linear*?

Comment: Yes, but in a sense I meant just the extra implementation effort is rewarding. I It could even consume less space, for cases where `term_variables(Vs, Ws), Vs == Ws`.

Answer (score 2):

If `copy_term/2` uses linear time, I believe the following works:

```
varset_intersection(As, Bs, Cs) :-
    copy_term(As-Bs, CopyAs-CopyBs),
    ground_list(CopyAs),
    select_grounded(CopyBs, Bs, Cs).

ground_list([]).
ground_list([a|Xs]) :-
    ground_list(Xs).

select_grounded([], [], []).
select_grounded([X|Xs], [_|Bs], Cs) :-
    var(X),
    !,
    select_grounded(Xs, Bs, Cs).
select_grounded([_|Xs], [B|Bs], [B|Cs]) :-
    select_grounded(Xs, Bs, Cs).
```

The idea is to copy both lists in one call to `copy_term/2` to preserve shared variables between them, then ground the variables of the first copy, then pick out the original variables of the second list corresponding to the grounded positions of the second copy.

Comment: Very nice surprise answer!

Comment: @false: Thanks, and thank you for the generous bounty!

Answer (score 1):

If `unify_with_occurs_check(Var, ListOfVars)` fails or succeeds in constant time, this implementation should yield answers in linear time:

```
filter_vars([], _, Acc, Acc).
filter_vars([A|As], Bs, Acc, As_cap_Bs):-
    (
        \+ unify_with_occurs_check(A, Bs)
      ->
        filter_vars(As, Bs, [A|Acc], As_cap_Bs)
      ;
        filter_vars(As, Bs, Acc, As_cap_Bs)
    ).

varset_intersection(As, Bs, As_cap_Bs):-
    filter_vars(As, Bs, [], Inter),
    permutation(Inter, As_cap_Bs).
```

This implementation has problems when given lists contain duplicates:

```
?- varset_intersection1([A,A,A,A,B], [B,A], L).
L = [B, A, A, A, A] ;

?- varset_intersection1([B,A], [A,A,A,A,B], L).
L = [A, B] ;
```

*Edited* : changed `bagof/3` to a manually written filter thanks to observation by @false in comments below.

Comment: Nice. Lifting the scan inside unify_with_occurs_check could work, if any implementation actually is able to do in constant time - which I think it's unlikely. Maybe permutation/2 it's just distracting...

Comment: `unify_with_occurs_check` requires in the worst case time proportional to the *entire* term.

Comment: `bagof/3` is quadratic: The witness of variables needs to contain all `As` and `Bs`. That is, for a single variable `V` |`As`|+|`Bs`| space is needed. This consideration is entirely independent of `unify_with_occurs_check/2`!

Comment: Thanks, I removed `bagof/3` and I wrote a different predicate to collect the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use a [Bloom filter](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362692). In case of collision, the result might be wrong, but functions with better collision resistance exist. Here is an implementation that uses a single hash function.

```
sum_codes([], _, Sum, Sum).
sum_codes([Head|Tail], K, Acc,Sum):-
    Acc1 is Head * (256 ** K) + Acc,
    K1 is (K + 1) mod 4,
    sum_codes(Tail, K1, Acc1, Sum).

hash_func(Var, HashValue):-
    with_output_to(atom(A), write(Var)),
    atom_codes(A, Codes),
    sum_codes(Codes, 0, 0, Sum),
    HashValue is Sum mod 1024.

add_to_bitarray(Var, BAIn, BAOut):-
    hash_func(Var, HashValue),
    BAOut is BAIn \/ (1 << HashValue).

bitarray_contains(BA, Var):-
    hash_func(Var, HashValue),
    R is BA /\ (1 << HashValue),
    R > 0.

varset_intersection(As, Bs, As_cap_Bs):-
    foldl(add_to_bitarray, As, 0, BA),
    include(bitarray_contains(BA), Bs, As_cap_Bs).
```

I know that `foldl/4` and `include/3` are not ISO, but their implementation is easy.

Comment: Note that in a standard conforming system `write(Var)` with `Var` being an uninstantiated variable, may always give the same text, like `_1`. So this solution depends on an implementation dependent feature (the naming of variables). Further, the names might change due to garbage collection in between. It is much much simpler!